# How to concatenate 3 histograms on the same graph in Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, plot, histogram

I have calculated 3 histograms for an rgb image using imhist function in Matlab, one for each channel. I want to plot these histograms on the same graph, where for instance, the histogram for the first (red) channel stretches on the x axis from 0 to 255, the histogram for the second channel stretches from 256 to 511, and finally the histogram for the third channel stretches from 512 to 767. 
How can I do this?

Comment: You really want to have them in the same graph? Or you want 3 subplots in one figure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `uint8` precision, each call to `imhist` will give you a 256 x 1 vector, and so you can concatenate these together into a single 768 x 1 vector.  After, call [`bar`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bar.html) with the `histc` flag.  Assuming you have your image stored in `im`, do this:

```
red = imhist(im(:,:,1));
green = imhist(im(:,:,2));
blue = imhist(im(:,:,3));
h = [red; green; blue];
bar(h, 'histc');
```

---

As an example, using the `onion.png` image that's part of the image processing toolbox:

```
im = imread('onion.png');
```

This is what the image looks like:

[image]

Using the above code to plot the concatenated histogram produces this graph:

[image]

Comment: Yeah, I made a mistake, what I meant to say was 0-255, and so on. This worked wonderfully. Thank you!